# how to openSSL 1.1.1 ECDH with 25519

Tags: c, openssl, ecdh, curve-25519

i need to implement ecdh with 25519 using openssl.

using:

```
key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X25519)
```

fails.

using this:

```
EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(NID_X25519, NULL);
EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(pctx);
EVP_PKEY_keygen(pctx, &pkey);
```

seems to work but i have no idea how to export the public key in uncompressed bin format. or how to import the other sides public key.

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing the other side's public key from raw binary format can be done with the EVP_PKEY_new_raw_public_key() function. Man page here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_new_raw_public_key.html

Exporting the public key in raw binary format is a little more tricky since there is no function to do it. You can do it in SubjectPublicKeyInfo format using i2d_PUBKEY() described here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/i2d_PUBKEY.html

Fortunately the SubjectPublicKeyInfo format has the raw public key as the last 32 bytes of its output. So you can use i2d_PUBKEY() and just use the last the 32 bytes.

Comment: I created an OpenSSL issue for the lack of function to export the raw key in binary format: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6259

Comment: EVP_PKEY_new_raw_public_key seems to create a new key, but how does that work with ECDH? i need to get it from the context or the EVP_PKEY i already created? and it still returns EVP_PKEY and not the row buffer

Comment: You need two EVP_PKEY objects. One containing your private/public key pair (i.e. the one you generated in the EVP_PKEY_keygen() call in your question), and one containing the public key of the peer (e.g. created using EVP_PKEY_new_raw_public_key()). To generate the X25519 shared secret you then call EVP_PKEY_derive(). See the example on the man page: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_derive.html

Comment: i2d_PUBKEY filled an array with:
first 4: 0x00 0x53 0xb5 0x01  all the rest are 0x00
but PEM_write_PUBKEY printed:
MCowBQYDK2VuAyEADzQvR1de+xLCZrth9eRv62fXAaJooth0xJj1uVE4y14=

Comment: Ah, I suspect you ran into a particular quirk of the OpenSSL API, namely that all the "i2d" functions increment the value of the supplied buffer to point to *after* the end of the DER encoded data. So if you immediately try to look at the data in the buffer without decrementing it again (or saving a pointer to the location of the original buffer) you just get rubbish back. See the description of i2d_TYPE() here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/d2i_X509.html

Comment: i saved passed a copy of the pointer to the i2d function and read the original pointer, same result as before. i checked the pointers before and after i2d and they are the same

Comment: What does the i2d function call return? If it is successful it should return a positive value that is the length of the encoded output. Can you post the code somewhere?

Comment: `EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_X25519, NULL);

    EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(pctx);

    EVP_PKEY_keygen(pctx, &pkey);

    userbin = (unsigned char **)&userSharedBin;

        printf("&userSharedBin=%p userbin=%p", &userSharedBin, userbin);

        userSharedBinSize = i2d_PUBKEY(openSslKey, userbin);

        printf("&userSharedBin=%p userbin=%p", &userSharedBin, 
userbin);

        LOG_INFO(threadIndex, "size is %d", userSharedBinSize);

`
the last print is 44

Comment: Why do you pass `openSslKey` in your call to `i2d_PUBKEY` and not `pkey`?

Comment: its from different functions, it is the same parameter, sorry for the confusion

Comment: `EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_X25519, NULL);
EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
unsigned char userSharedBin[100];
unsigned char *userbin;
int userSharedBinSize;

EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(pctx);
EVP_PKEY_keygen(pctx, &pkey);

userbin = userSharedBin;
printf("&userSharedBin=%p userbin=%p\n", &userSharedBin, userbin);

userSharedBinSize = i2d_PUBKEY(pkey, &userbin);
printf("&userSharedBin=%p userbin=%p\n", &userSharedBin, userbin);
printf("size is %d\n", userSharedBinSize);

BIO_dump_fp(stdout, userSharedBin, userSharedBinSize);`

Comment: I made some tweaks to your code. The above now works for me as expected.

Comment: i got the other side ECP_PKEY, how do i compute the shared secret?

Comment: i'm having trouble importing i2d output to mbedTLS format and i see that its not the expected format.

what is the 'row' format?

Comment: Use the `EVP_PKEY_derive` function to derive a shared secret: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_PKEY_derive.html

Comment: after derive, do i get the actual X point or i get it hashed (for use as a key)?

Comment: You have to hash it yourself.